# regex - negative expression matching

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

**Problem Introduction**

So I've fried my brain trying to get negative look ahead/behinds to work. For the last example input, my current solution returns no match (see expected output table). I'm struggling with how to match the `title` part of the string when it includes a year that is not at the end of the string. To be clear, I'm only interested in matching the `year` if it is at the end of the string. The current regex fails on the last example, as it is matching `NOT("Q" OR "\d*")` in the `title`. However, I only want it to match `NOT("Q" AND "\d{1}")`. Any tips/suggestions greatly appreciated. Note using Python 3.8.

**Example Input**

```
AXP - Earnings call Q2 2021
AXP - Conference call 2021
BAC,BAC.PE,BAC.PL,BACRP,BML.PL,BML.PJ,BML.PH,BML.PG,BAC.PB,BAC.PK,BAC.PM,BAC.PN - Earnings call Q2 2021
GM - General Motors Company (GM) Presents at Deutsche Bank AutoTech Conference
AXP - American Express Company (AXP) Management Presents at Barclays 2020 Global Financial Services Conference
```

The `period` will always be of the form `Q[1-4]`. `period` and `year` are optional. If they do occur, they will be at the end of the string. `symbol` and `title` are always separated by `-` and always occur.

**Expected Output**

| symbol | title | period | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AXP | Earnings call | Q2 | 2021 |
| AXP | Conference call |  | 2021 |
| BAC | Earnings call | Q2 | 2021 |
| GM | General Motors Company (GM) Presents at Deutsche Bank AutoTech Conference |  |  |
| AXP | American Express Company (AXP) Management Presents at Barclays 2020 Global Financial Services Conference |  |  |

**What I've Tried**

```
r"^(?P<symbol>[^\,]{1,8})(\,[A-Z\.]+)*\s\-\s(?P<title>[^Q\d]*)\s?(?P<period>Q\d)?\s?(?P<year>19|20\d{2})$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?P<symbol>[^,]{1,8})(?:,[A-Z.]*)*\s+-\s+(?P<title>(?:(?!Q\d).)*?)\s*(?P<period>Q\d)?\s?(?P<year>(?:19|20)\d{2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKQn8p/2).

*Note*:

- `[^Q\d]*` is wrong as it matches any zero or more chars other than `Q` and digit, you need to match any text up to a `Q` + digit, that is, a `(?:(?!Q\d).)*?` tempered greedy token
- `(?P<year>19|20\d{2})` is obligatory, but it must be optional and `19|20` are not grouped, so `\d{2}` is only applied to `20`, `(?P<year>19|20\d{2})` => `(?P<year>(?:19|20)\d{2})?`.

There are other small enhancements here.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<symbol>[^,]{1,8})` - Group "symbol": one to eight chars other than a comma
- `(?:,[A-Z.]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of a comma and then zero or more uppercase letters/dots
- `\s+-\s+` - a hyphen enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(?P<title>(?:(?!Q\d).)*?)` - Group "title": any char other than a line break char, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start a `Q`+digit char sequence
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?P<period>Q\d)?` - Group "period": a `Q` and a digit
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `(?P<year>(?:19|20)\d{2})?` - an optional Group "year": `19` or `20` and then two digits
- `$` - end of string.